# The Coordinate ring $A(X)$ is a field if and only if $X$ is a singleton

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

> Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be an affine variety. Show that the coordinate ring $A(X)$ is a field if and only if $X$ is a singleton.
>
> Remark: This is exercise 1.20 from Gathmann's Notes "Algebraic Geometry". The coordinate ring $A(X)$ is defined as $A(X) := K[x_1,\ldots,x_n] / I(X)$, where $I(X)$ denotes the vanishing ideal of $X$.

I realise that if $X = {a}$ for some $a \in K$, then $I(X) = \{ (x-a) \cdot p \mid p \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \}$, but I do not see how to proceed from here. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: What does Hilbert nullstellensatz say about the maximal ideals of the ring?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $K$ is algebraically closed.